# SQL ClicHouse | Разбить месяц на дни

Tags: sql, база-данных, clickhouse

Всем привет!

Имеется таблица

| date | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-20 | 1 |
| 2021-12-21 | 2 |
| 2021-12-22 | 1 |
| 2021-12-23 | 3 |
| 2021-12-24 | 3 |
| 2021-12-25 | 1 |
| 2021-12-26 | 1 |

- Как мне разбить месяц по 2 дня и получить такую таблицу?
- Использую SQL ClickHouse

| date | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-20 | 3 |
| 2021-12-22 | 4 |
| 2021-12-24 | 4 |
| 2021-12-26 | 1 |

Comment: ```GROUP BY DAY(`date`) DIV 2```?

Comment: - Получаю ошибку
SQL Error [215] [07000]: Code: 215. DB::Exception: Column `date` is not under aggregate function and not in GROUP BY  

- Мой код
`SELECT DayOfMonth(date), count(cnt)
FROM table
GROUP BY DAY(date) DIV 2
ORDER BY 1`

Comment: `DayOfMonth(date)` - с какого перепугу-то? Должно быть ```MIN(`date`)```.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм решения сделан в Access. Группирует, начиная с чётного дня:

```
SELECT First(Table2.Adate) AS PeriodStart, Sum(Table2.cnt) AS SumOfcnt
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Day([Adate])\2;
```